# how can i create a responsive mouseover tooltip using a background image?

Tags: css, image, tooltip, hint

css to create some tooltips when mousing over some text. the text is positioned relative to the parent div inside it's own div. I need the background image to be responsive so that when the browser resizes to a lower res the image responds, as well as the text that is positioned over the image.

As of now everything works but if I resize the browser the text that is positioned over the image does not respond. and becomes out of position copmpared to the image below it.
thanks

Comment: please post your current `html` and `css` so that we have something to work with.

Comment: Hi i'll get something up a bit later. thx

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of libraries for tooltips. I would suggest you use one of those.

Examples:

1. [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)
2. [tooltipsy](http://tooltipsy.com/)